# CONVERT PHP ARRAY TO JSON (empty body)

Tags: php, json

i have no content to show even i use this code ,

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);                
            $indexCourses=[];
            $listCourses=array();               
            $listCourses=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($listCourses,TRUE);
```

the output of my array with **print_r()** is :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [nom] => Marathon de Marrakech [date] => 
28/01/2018 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [nom] => Semi marathon Meknès [date] 
=> 18/02/2018 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 8 [nom] => 10 km de Casablanca 
(ENSEM) [date] => 25/02/2018 ) )
```

any help please

Comment: The correct usage of `json_encode` is `echo json_encode($listCourses);`

Comment: even with echo json_encode($listCourses) doesn't work , the body is empty !!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your data json_encode probably throws and error when trying to encode non-UTF8 characters. You can check if the error is occurred by using  [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) function. Additionally, please read on how to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function (specifically second argument specs), because I think you don't need to pass the second argument to the function in your case.

The solution to your problem might be quite simple - when creating mysqli connection use UTF8 encoding, which will force all the results to be returned in UTF8 as well, in which case json_encode will not have the problem.

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

(taken from https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp)